# Cannot change drive letter in console of Media Creation Tool medium

Tags: windows, windows-10, console

I start from a USB-stick created via MCT and open up the console via **Shift** + **F10**,

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption
```

shows me a list of available volumes, of which C: is present. But when typing

```
cd C:\
```

my cursor stays on volume **X:\**.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If MCT is just the media creation tool from microsoft then typing.

```
C:
```

Should be enough.